# Is a 50-76hz monitor 50 or 76 hz? or is it somewhere in between?

Tags: display, desktop-computer

So, [this monitor](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=3709664&Sku=H24-23710) on Tiger Direct (that seems to be a great deal) says it has a 50-76hz refresh rate. Does this mean it is 50, 60, or 76hz?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any authoritative source, and the best way to find out for sure would be to contact the manufacturer (HP in this case), but it probably means it will accept any refresh rate in that range.

Related posts from some forums (not authoritative sources, but the only logical explanation anyway):

- http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/369586-33-what-refresh-rate-moniter
- http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1653025/refresh-rates-monitors-range.html

Comment: I would assume the same, that it's a range that is listed.

Comment: oh i see. So it can definately handle 60hz (that's what's important), but theoretically it could go up to 76. Thanks for your response!